# How to disable PHP extensions that I don't use?

Tags: php, module, php-ini, disable

PHP 8, by default, has an entire list of extensions which can't be removed. Or, at least, I can't see a way to removed them using php.ini.

The list of those which can't be removed is this:

```
Core
PDO
Phar
Reflection
SPL
SimpleXML
apache2handler
bcmath
calendar
ctype
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mysqlnd
pcre
readline
session
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib
```

1. I may not want to use the zip extension at all. Then why can't be removed ?
2. There is any way to get the list of extensions which can't be disabled ?

Comment: Likely because they've been compiled into the PHP binary you're using because they are very commonly used. Why are you so insistent on disabling everything?

Comment: @Sammitch Well, extensions like xdebug may affect the performance of an application. And I don't have a list of extensions which can harm my application (yes, I know, it's about miliseconds). So I want to take control of extensions loaded.

Comment: It depends on how it was compiled. Any extension that was compiled shared will have a separate `.so` file associated with it, and can be "removed" by commenting out the appropriate `extension=whatever.so` in the `php.ini` file. If the extension was not compiled shared, then it's innate in the PHP binary and can't be removed. If you *really* want to remove them, you'll have to recompile PHP yourself and exclude that module during compilation configuration.

Comment: As others have said, this depends how PHP was compiled. On an Ubuntu system, for instance, most of the extensions in your list are not even installed by default. Since you didn't say how you've installed PHP, the question is basically unanswerable.

Comment: ... and then delete your redundant comment-answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a module is "removable" depends on how it was compiled. For example, you can compile each module as a built-in:

```
./configure --with-zip
```

Or as shared:

```
./configure --with-zip=shared
```

In the former case, the module will be included directly in the PHP binary. It can not be removed -- if you really don't want it, you'd have to recompile without specifying `--with-zip`.

In the latter case, you'll get a separate `zip.so` file that contains all the module code, and gets loaded at runtime. This  module can be "removed" simply by commenting out (or deleting) the appropriate `extension=zip.so` in the `php.ini` file. This doesn't actually uninstall anything, it just tells PHP not to load the shared module when it starts.